# How to clean up/straighten 3D models from photogrammetry or scan

Tags: 3d, blender

3D models from scans or photogrammetry contain models of buildings that are all messed up, contain many angles, and have no straight lines aka 'walls'.

Is there a way to clean this up, essentially probably draw new straight lines along the outline of the building? In the image, the green lines represent what I mean with the start of a new model.

If you have to do this by hand it's almost as easy as just starting from scratch (model from a photo of the building)

[image: 3D rendering of a building from photogrammetry]

Comment: This has really nothing to do with graphic design. Photogrammetry is always quite noisy. Either render it as is or model on top of it and project details as maps.

Comment: It's straightened best in the photo shooting session. The roof looks well imaged. I guess the rest of the house would be too (except the glossy windows and what's behind the trees), if there were enough photos from different directions. Obviously the camera has taken very few shots to other directions than downwards. The 2nd option is to redraw it.